# Paperclip images not Displaying in rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, image, paperclip

I'm using paperclip to upload images to the site but when I do, it shows the image placeholder with a question mark, not the image itself. What Am I doing wrong?
In the model:

```
     attr_accessor :photo_file_name
     attr_accessor :photo_content_type
    attr_accessor :photo_file_size
    attr_accessor :photo_updated_at
    attr_accessible :photo


#paperclip-------------------------------
 has_attached_file :photo,
                 :url => "/:attachment/:id/:style/:basename.:extension",
                 :path => ":rails_root/public/:attachment/:id/:style/:basename.:extension"
```

In the view:

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>
<div id="container">
<div id="content">
<%= image_tag @post.photo.url %>
<p>
  <b>Title:</b>
   <%= @post.title %>
```

and in the form I have:

```
<div class="field">
<%= post_form.file_field :photo %>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you check whether the image file is stored :rails_root/public/:attachment/:id/:style/ yet?

Right click to the image place holder to check the url of the image, is it right?

Comment: Ok, I right-clicked on the image and the url is wrong, it's looking in photos/original/missing.png instead of photos/11/original

Comment: @user1191343 but why it was showing path for missing.png. I have same issue, how did you resolve it.

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of all the accessor stuff and make sure your form returns something like:

`params[:post][:photo]`

Typically via:

```
form_for @post do |f|
  f.file_field :photo
end
```

Then, in your posts controller, you can update or otherwise save a particular post with a `:photo` attached. Display the photo by simply tagging it `image_tag @post.photo`, Paperclip can do the rest.

I highly recommend removing your `:url` and `:path` options and just use the default for now, which is fine for most applications. It includes the `system/` directory that is symlinked as shared by default under Capistrano, which is nice.

Comment: not sure i understand, so basically put  f.file_field params[:photo]?

Comment: Nope, just `:photo`. It exists as an attribute of the model in forms.

Comment: WHen i right-click on the image it takes me to photos/origianal/missing.png